# asp.net autocomplete extender and forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, autocomplete

I am using an autocomplete extender in a site that is set to use forms authentication, however I am not using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. Instead, the authCookie is being created and added to the Response. The automcomplete is set up to use a page method in the containing page. The method is decorated with both `WebMethod` and `ScriptMethod` attributes.

The problem occurs when I try to activate the autocomplete, i receive a dialog to authenticate to the web server. I am already on the page that the web method belongs to, I don't understand why the service call is requiring me to authenticate again. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: It turned out to be cross site authentication request because the autocomplete was calling COMPUTERNAME.DOMAINNAME where as the site itself was being called up under LOCALHOST. I should have recognized it earlier but all I had to do was copy the COMPUTERNAME.DOMAINNAME and use that in for the URL in place of LOCALHOST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be cross site authentication request because the autocomplete was calling COMPUTERNAME.DOMAINNAME where as the site itself was being called up under LOCALHOST. I should have recognized it earlier but all I had to do was copy the COMPUTERNAME.DOMAINNAME and use that in for the URL in place of LOCALHOST.